# Getting Error while Installing Solr 7.5.0 - 0x80090020

Tags: solr

Getting error while setting up `Solr 7.5.0`, on `SSL` set step to add as root CA
Script used:

https://gitlab.com/viet.hoang/workshop/blob/master/Scripts%20for%20Sitecore%209.1/install-solr.ps1

VM Server:

```
Trusting generated SSL certificate...

**Import-PfxCertificate : An internal error occurred. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80090020)
At C:\sitecore\sc920_install\install-solr.ps1:93 char:9
+ $root = Import-PfxCertificate -FilePath $P12Path -Password $secureStr ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Import-PfxCertificate], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException,Microsoft.CertificateServices.Commands.ImportPfxCertificate**
```

Local sever: Went fine same script on same step followed.

```
Trusting generated SSL certificate...
SSL certificate is now locally trusted. (added as root CA)
Resetting solr.in.cmd
Rewriting solr config
Installing Solr service
Service "solr-7.5.0" installed successfully!
Starting Solr service...
```

Any experience share would be appreciated.

Comment: Permissions issue?

Comment: Not sure, But work around is to create solr-ssl.keystore.p12 outside the server and transfer to server for installation. It depends and no clue. No all outside system created solr-ssl.keystore.p12 takes it up. strange error(permission or machine specific lock etc). tried couple of system file and among one worked.